# WCF Connection Error

Tags: wcf

When the WCF service is deployed on Localhost the connection works fine. On deploying it to a server the following error is occurring on **method call**:

**Outer exception:**

> There was no endpoint listening at
>   http://subdomain.xyz.in/Service.svc
>   that could accept the message. This is
>   often caused by an incorrect address
>   or SOAP action. See InnerException, if
>   present, for more details.

**Inner Exception:**

When Default proxy is enabled:

> No connection could be made because
>   the target machine actively refused it
>   127.0.0.1:8888

When Default proxy is disabled:

> No connection could be made because
>   the target machine actively refused it
>   192.168.xxx.xxx:80

The service is accessible by browsing the svc file in web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide proxy details for your client - best put in your config file although you can set it in code as well. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Two things you might want to check into. One, are you using 'localhost' in the connection details, and two: is http://subdomain.xyz.in is a valid url.

IF the second one fails, then DNS might be your issue in pointing to the wrong place.
The first one is a configuration issue and instead of using localhost, use http://subdomain.xyz.in since sharepoint is designed to run from a /farm/, not just a single server. Any one of those machines might call the service and if you don't plan to deploy your service to all of those machines, then well... it's just not going to work since they're trying to talk to themselves instead of where the service is located.

Kind of like you trying to call a friend on the phone and using your own phone number. It just doesn't quite work that way.